# Why is my app periodically killed?

Tags: ubuntu

My app is periodically (once a few days) killed on Ubuntu 22.04 VPS with 1GB RAM:

[image]

why this can happen?

is it possible that this is because the system runs out of memory or swap?

What logs can I check?

Comment: The `dmesg` command shows the kernel ringbuffer and is where you can usually see  if the OoM killer was activated & killed your process.